# How to have a static pop-up that stays in place even if the user navigates away?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I create a pop-up or overlay that stays in place even when I navigate to various pages of the same website?

The example I have in mind is that Chat box on the bottom right of facebook.com.

Comment: Learn how to make a single page application.

Comment: this relates to the so-called ***session***. The info about the popup should be saved in session and should be shown on every pages the current user navigates to. Of course at each time loading a new page, the popup won't be shown instantly, it depends on how you load your pages.